# How to get the contents of the "Country" field in the Calendar settings throw API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to get the contents of a field "Country" in Google Calendar Settings - General - Language and Region throw API (maybe Calendar API)

[image]

I'm trying to find a method to get/change the content of the field Country via Google API

Comment: you cant get country best you can get would be timezone.

Comment: I understand, thanks, but unfortunately I need to get exactly the values ​​of the "Country" field. If I understand correctly, in the current version of the API there is no way to get the values ​​​​of this particular field?

Comment: That is correct I searched the api myself and can find no response objects that include a country